# Cannot read property 'getBounds'. with addListenerOnce

Tags: javascript, google-maps

belows are my codes. I have added google.maps.event.addListenerOnce but still getting this error. Not sure how can it be resolved. Thanks.

'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBounds' of undefined'

```
var map;
var service;

function handleSearchResults(results, status)
{
    console.log(results);
}

function performSearch()
{
var request = {
    bounds: map.getBounds(),
    name: "McDonald's",
    } 
service.nearbySearch(request, handleSearchResults); 
}

function initialise(location)
{
    console.log(location);

    var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);

    var mapOptions = {
    center: currentLocation,
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeID: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP    
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: currentLocation,
        map: map            
    });

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'bounds_changed', performSearch);

}


$(document).ready(function()
{
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialise);       
});
```

Comment: can you share your performSearch() function and tell where the error is triggered?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not fluent in js, but it seems that the "map" var in "initialize" function is not the same as the global one (as set by the "var" keyword in front of both).